# Prevent Double Submit in Stateless react-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm a react newbie (My apologies). I'm a little stuck on this one.

I'm building some react components with submit buttons that make calls to a RESTful API. With a stateful component, here's how I was preventing "double submits" (essentially change the state while the request is processing)

```
class Submitter extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { buttonDisabled: false, buttonText: 'Save' };
    this.saveQuestion = this.saveQuestion.bind(this);
  }

  saveToApi() {
    const _this = this;
    this.setState({ buttonDisabled: true, buttonText: 'Saving' });
    request((err, res) => {
      _this.setState({ buttonDisabled: false, buttonText: 'Save' });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>
      <TextInput />
      <Button 
        disabled={this.state.buttonDisabled} 
        onClick={this.saveToApi}>
      {this.state.buttonText}
      </Button>
    </div>);
  }

}
```

This has worked great. I started to use [react-form](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-form) to do some more advanced validations, etc. However, it's a stateless component, and I'm at a loss for how to do it. I'm not using redux, but I can if I need to. Even if I was using redux, I'm not sure the general strategy about how to go about it. Here's my working login form, but it doesn't prevent the double submit.

```
const LoginForm = Form({
  validate: values => {
    const { email, password } = values;
    return {
      email: (!email || !/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email)) ? 'A valid email is required' : undefined,
      password: (!password || password.length < 6) ? 'Passwords must be longer than 6 characters' : undefined,
    };
  },
})(({ submitForm }) => (<form onSubmit={submitForm}>
    <FormTextInput htmlId="email" label="Email Address" />
    <FormTextInput htmlId="password" label="Password" type="password" />
    <Button colored type="raised" htmlType="submit" >Login</Button>
  </form>
  ));

export default () => (
    <LoginForm
      onSubmit={(values) => {
        request((err, res) => {
          if (res.body.login) {
            history.push('/app');
          } else {
            msg.error(res.body.message);
          }
        });
      }}
    />
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) function like so:

```
_saveToApi(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: That would work for the first example, but I'm more interested in the second example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to prevent default `html` submit.

So wrap your `form` `submit` which has `event` by default in `LoginForm` component.

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   submitForm();
  }
}>
    <FormTextInput htmlId="email" label="Email Address" />
    <FormTextInput htmlId="password" label="Password" type="password" />
    <Button colored type="raised" htmlType="submit" >Login</Button>
</form>
```